# Changing JTable in Java and exporting it in a file

Tags: java, swing, jtable, addeventlistener

i have a task to visualize a *.csv file using Swift and allowing the user to edit the information and exporting it to another file. I have managed to display the data in a JTable, but i cannot find any solution about how to update the table after changing it. I was thinking of creating another table using the same model, but it seems that the fields were not updated, even when pressing on another box or hitting the Enter. I am done with the exporting part also . Can anyone help out with this. Thanks in advance ! I can share some code if needed.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by _update a table after changing it_?

Comment: I mean that when I update a cell after I export the table nothing seems to be updated and this makes me think that nothing was updated

Comment: If you mean you are not able to edit the cell in the JTable, then you have probably made the table non-editable or there is some other problem with the code. We may be able to help more if you post the relevant code.

Comment: When I get home I will post it. Thanks :)

Comment: So here is my PrintCSV class - http://pastebin.com/MtJuPFvE - after i print it i export the data to another csv file with the ExportCSV class - http://pastebin.com/seH4jEJt. I think i 'm missing some kind of event handler to process the event of cell value changing.